# simple icmp traceroute implementation in C

Tags: c, sockets, icmp, traceroute

OK, so I tried to write a simple ICMP traceroute using materials from my lecturer which were echo_request and icmp_receive programs which I wanted to merge to achieve my goal but it kind of doesn't work.

So my code looks like this(it's not the final version of traceroute - just a fragment that i thought should give some results):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include "sockwrap.h"
#include "icmp.h"
#include <time.h>

unsigned char   buffer[IP_MAXPACKET+1];
unsigned char*  buffer_ptr;
int             re;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: ./traceroute <ip>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int sockfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    
    struct sockaddr_in remote_address;
    bzero (&remote_address, sizeof(remote_address));
    remote_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &remote_address.sin_addr);

    int ttl = 1;

    while(1){
        struct icmp icmp_packet;
        icmp_packet.icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
        icmp_packet.icmp_code = 0;
        icmp_packet.icmp_id = 123;      
        icmp_packet.icmp_seq = ttl;     
        icmp_packet.icmp_cksum = 0;
        icmp_packet.icmp_cksum = in_cksum((u_short*)&icmp_packet, 8, 0);

        Setsockopt (sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(int));
        
        Sendto(sockfd, &icmp_packet, ICMP_HEADER_LEN, 0, &remote_address, sizeof(remote_address));
        Sendto(sockfd, &icmp_packet, ICMP_HEADER_LEN, 0, &remote_address, sizeof(remote_address));
        Sendto(sockfd, &icmp_packet, ICMP_HEADER_LEN, 0, &remote_address, sizeof(remote_address));

        clock_t start = clock();
        float seconds = 0;
        while(seconds < 1){
            clock_t c = clock();
            seconds = (float)(c - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        }

        struct sockaddr_in sender;  
        socklen_t sender_len = sizeof(sender);
        buffer_ptr = buffer;
        re = Recvfrom (sockfd, buffer_ptr, IP_MAXPACKET, 
                                            0, &sender, &sender_len);

        char str[20]; 
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sender.sin_addr), str, sizeof(str));
        // this printf shows me ip adresses of routers on route to 
        // destination(probably?), but anything below it doesn't seem to work
        // properly :(
        //printf ("%s\n", str);

        struct icmp* icmp_packet_recv = (struct icmp*) buffer_ptr;

        printf("%d %d\n", icmp_packet_recv->icmp_id, icmp_packet_recv->icmp_seq);

        if (icmp_packet_recv->icmp_type == ICMP_TIME_EXCEEDED && 
            icmp_packet_recv->icmp_code == ICMP_EXC_TTL) {

            struct ip* packet_orig = (struct ip*) buffer_ptr;

            if (packet_orig->ip_p == IPPROTO_ICMP) {
                if(icmp_packet_recv->icmp_seq == ttl && icmp_packet_recv->icmp_id == 123)
                    printf ("%s\n", str);
            }
        }
        if (icmp_packet_recv->icmp_type == ICMP_ECHOREPLY) {
            printf ("%s\n", str);
            return 0;
        }

        ttl++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It kind of works, because when I print the ip of sender, it looks like it's tracerouting, but when I want to check a package that I'm receiving, it conains different `icmp_id` and `icmp_seq` from what I've sent.
It seems strange to me, because when I run `echo_request` and `icmp_receive` and I send a package with `id` 123 and `seq` 1, I receive the exact same `id` and `seq`, but in my program it's different.

If you could point out where I'm doing stupid things in my code and explain that, I would be grateful. This task turned out harder than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `re` after call to `Recvfrom`. There can be an error or different length of what you are expecting.

Also, as I remember, with this RAW socket you will get **all** ICMP packets sent to your network interface; so you need to receive all packets and work only with packets which contain the same sequence number.

And I could not see `bind()`. Isn't it necessary?

Comment: Recvfrom is a wrapper for recvfrom in which I check for errors. From what i know there is no need for bind() with ICMP packets. What really bothers me is why my program never reaches the part where I'm checking for time exceeded and echo reply.

Comment: Try to receive packets in internal loop and print data for each packet.

Comment: Hm, could you tell me what do I have to check to know that received "time exceeded" packet is actually a response to my "echo request"? `icmp_id` and `icmp_seq` are the same only when I get `ICMP_ECHOREPLY` packet, but when I get `ICMP_TIME_EXCEEDED` they seem random.